# Check if two objects have equal content in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm learning how to use Pytest (and unit testing in general) and I would like to write a test to check if two objects of the same class have identical attributes.

Example:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Something(a={}, b={})'.format(self.a, self.b)

def test_equality():
    obj1 = Something(1, 2)
    obj2 = Something(1, 2)
    assert obj1.a == obj2.a
    assert obj1 == obj2
```

This test fails with AssertionError on third assert:

```
    def test_equality():
        obj1 = Something(1, 2)
        obj2 = Something(1, 2)
        assert obj1.a == obj2.a
        assert obj1.b == obj2.b                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>       assert obj1 == obj2                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
E       assert Something(a=1, b=2) == Something(a=1, b=2)                                                                                                                                                                                     

tests/test_model.py:13: AssertionError
```

It is possible in Python or Pytest to use just `assert obj1 == obj2`? Should I implement "rich comparison" methods for each class I would like to test that way or there is some simpler way?

Comment: Usually it is better to implement a comparison operator, like `__eq__`, since some objects can be equal, even if the fields are not. An *ugly* hack that usually works if (a) the attributes themselves are comparable, and (b) all attributes are stored in the dict work is `type(obj1) == type(obj2) and obj1.__dict__ == obj2.__dict__`, but this is very limited.

Comment: @Idos: Yes, it looks very similar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Override the __eq__ function of Something.

```
def __eq__(self, other)
    if isinstance(self, other.__class__):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
    return False
```

Also.

```
assert obj1 == obj2
```

is actually a two-part statement. first is the expression obj1 == obj2, which calls obj1.__eq__(obj2) and returns a boolean, the second asserts that boolean for truth.

Comment: Overriding the __eq__ operator could have unintended consequences here, depending on how the uniqueness of this object is determined.

Comment: @MichaelRobellard How? If reference equality is expected, the __is__ operator should be used. It is clear the OP wishes to define two objects of Something as equal if their fields are equivalent.

Comment: if you override the __eq__ you should know the uniqueness should be. For me this is the correct answer.

Comment: I need to override just __eq__? I thought I need to implement all six methods, but just one it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: An example of where this would be bad is if you subclass your class, do you want a subclass with both those properties set to be equal to the base class? Sometimes you would want to and sometimes not. depends on the circumstances.

Comment: In that case, the equals operator should be overrided in the subclass as well with any additional fields or equivalence parameters necessary for the subclass and a call to the superclass eq, that's an architecture problem, I don't think its a problem intrinsically with overriding \__eq__

Comment: There isn't a problem with overriding __eq__ necessarily.  I just think it could easily bite someone that doesn't realize all the ramifications.

Comment: Indeed, as are all decisions to override any method and combine with inheritance in oo languages.